# bash if statement, is a version less than required?

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, version

i'm writing dependency checking into a program, and i require a particular program to be at least a particular version.

this is what i have so far..

```
gtkdialog_v=`gtkdialog --version | sed -e "s| |\n|g" -e "/^$/d" | grep "[0-9]\."`
if [ "$gtkdialog_v" -lt "0.8.3" ]; then echo "gtkdialog must be version 0.8.3 or higher"; exit; fi
```

"-lt" is the issue, if i insert "=" then it functions as expected, if i use "<" it errors the same as "-lt"

my error

```
[: 0.8.3: integer expression expected
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Newer versions of `GNU coreutils` provide `sort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [Natural Sort](http://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order) to do this:

```
#!/bin/sh
min=0.8.3
ver=0.8.2

if shuf -e $min{,} $ver | sort -V | awk '{getline b;exit$0==b?0:1}'
then
  echo 'good'
else
  echo 'gtkdialog must be version 0.8.3 or higher'
  exit
fi
```

Comment: that works perfectly for any case i can think to test. thank you

Answer (score 1):

`-lt` can be applied only to integer expressions. But you are using it to compare string expressions. bash doesn't have support for floating point operations.

Instead compare the strings:

```
if [[ "$gtkdialog_v" < "0.8.3" ]];
```

Note this will do ASCII comparison (not integer comparison). For example,

```
if [[ "0.12.3" < "0.8.3" ]]; then
  echo yes
fi
```

will print "yes" which is not what expected.

Comment: the second example works (for now) in my case because 0.8.x is the highest version for this program, but it would fail to work if the developer goes to 0.10.0 before 1.0.0, any better fix would be appreciated.

Comment: @user2225483 You can use awk: `echo 0.12 0.13 | awk '{ if($1 > $2) {print $1} else {print $2}}'` Pass the those strings and compare.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath `<` does work with `[` (bash's version of it, anyway), just not the way it was done in this answer (before the edit). So long as you escape/quote it, it won't be parsed as a file redirection.

Answer (score 0):

`-lt` expected an integer expression, not a string containing a value in floating point format. so it errored out. I think you can tweak it a little bit and remove the `.` So `0.8.3` becomes `083` and then you can check with `0.8.5 => 085`. But this will work iff the version seq is straight forward.  Or another approach is you cut them and start comparing each field